# Making request to same a RestEndpoint simultaneously using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a node js server with the following endpoint below, In python, I want to send multiple requests to the endpoint simultaneously.

After reading multiple similar posts on this matter, I have tried to  asyncio and multi-threading, demonstrated by my code below.

I know each request individually takes ~0.256 seconds. With multithreading and async request, I am expecting the time taken to complete 8 requests to be close to ~0.256 seconds. However, this is not the result.

Node JS endpoint

```
app.post('/postImage' ,async function(req,res){
   const imgBase64 = req.body.imgBase64;
   const poseKeypoints = await getPoseDetection(imgBase64) 
   res.send(JSON.stringify({detectionList:poseKeypoints}))

});//End of app.post and asyn function
```

Python Code To make the request

```
def process_urls(session,playload):
    data = playload['data']
    proc_id = playload['id']
    start = time.time()

    url2 = 'http://localhost:3000/postImage'
    with session.post(url=url2 , data = data) as response:
        poses = response.json()

    url2 = 'http://localhost:3000/getBBox'
    with session.post(url=url2) as response:
        bboxes = response.json()

    end = time.time()
    print(f'Request ID : {proc_id}, Time:{round(end-start,3)}')
    playloads[proc_id]['poses'] = poses
    playloads[proc_id]['boxes'] = boxes
    #print(f'Finish For proc:{proc_id}')

async def get_data_asynchronous():
    start = time.time()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        with req.Session() as session:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor,process_urls,*(session,playload)) for playload in playloads ]
            for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
                pass
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Total Time for all Request : {round(end-start , 2)}')


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(get_data_asynchronous())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)

main()
```

Time taken for 8 request

```
Request ID : 0, Time:0.567
Request ID : 3, Time:0.587
Request ID : 1, Time:1.57
Request ID : 2, Time:1.592
Request ID : 4, Time:1.586
Request ID : 5, Time:1.581
Request ID : 7, Time:1.568Request ID : 6, Time:1.577

Total Time for all Request : 1.61
```

My question is why is the request time per process not ~0.25 seconds? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for helping out.

Comment: You expect parallel execution on the server by using multiple threading on the client?

Comment: I am new to this, whats the mistake? @OrestisZekai